# Not printing 1st Node entered in stack(toString)

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes, comparable, stack

First off, the code is long, but I am only concerned about the toString method. I pasted everything in case its relevant.

The code is supposed to check whether or not the element entered is less than the element at the top of the stack. I have that part figured out. When I call my toString method to print the saved input, it doesn't print the first node added to the stack. However, it prints all remaining inputs. A example would be if a user enters the following:

```
testing
test
te
t

What its currently outputing:
t te test

What it needs to output:
t te test testing
```

Main:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Stack {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int loopInt = 1;
    PyramidStack<String> stringStack = new PyramidStack<String>();
    PyramidStack<Integer> intStack = new PyramidStack<Integer>();

    System.out
            .println("This program will save some of the strings you enter. ");
    System.out
            .println("Can you predict which ones will be saved?  (Enter nothing to quit.)");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); // Opens Scanner for keyboard input

    try {
        do {
            System.out.print("Enter a String: ");
            String input = sc.nextLine();

            if (input.length() > 0) {

                if (stringStack.size() == 0) {
                    intStack.push(input.length());
                    stringStack.push(input);
                    System.out.println("String Saved");
                }

                else if (input.length() < intStack.peek()) {
                    stringStack.push(input);
                    intStack.push(input.length());
                    System.out.println("String Saved");

                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("String NOT saved. Already saved "
                            + intStack.countBefore(input.length())
                            + " strings that should come before this one.");
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println(stringStack.toString());
                System.out.println(intStack.toString());

                loopInt--;
                sc.close();
            }
        } while (loopInt > 0);

    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        System.out.println("No strings have been entered. Ending the program.");
    }
}
}
```

PyramidStack Method:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.Comparable;

public class PyramidStack<E extends Comparable<E>> extends Stack<E> {

@Override
public void push(E item) throws IllegalArgumentException {

    if (super.size == 0) {
        super.push(item);

    }
    else if(item.compareTo(super.peek()) <= 0) {

        super.push(item);
    } 
    else {
        System.out.println("String NOT saved. " + countBefore(item) +  " strings that should come before this one.");
    }
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    Node<E> node;
    node = this.top;
    String s = "";

    while(node.getNext() != null){
        s += node.getData() + " ";
        node = node.getNext();
    }    
    return s;
}


public int countBefore(E item) {
    Node<E> node;
    node = this.top;
    int i = 0;

    while(node.getNext() != null){
        if(item.compareTo(super.peek()) <= 0) {
        node = node.getNext();
        }
        else{
        i++;
        node = node.getNext();
        }
    }
    return i;
}
}
```

Stack method and Node Method below in comments.

Comment: Paste-bin of Node and Stack Class.http://pastebin.com/N4Q1j6Tn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`while(node.getNext() != null){
        s += node.getData() + " ";
        node = node.getNext();
    }`

This is where you are missing to print the last data.. you are checking node.getnext() is null.. so it skips the last object and doesn't print that.. your condition should be
`node != null`
**OR**
After the loop end have this
`s += node.getData()`  -- this will not give null pointer exception as node is not null.. as it did check node.getnext()

Hope it helps

Comment: That is basically the explanation I was looking for. That is what I assumed was the problem, just didn't know how to implement it. Thanks for the help!